# Custom Allocator in C

Tags: c, malloc, allocation

I'm trying to understand how does custom memory allocator works and I stumbled upon [this](https://github.com/Snaipe/malloc/blob/master/malloc.c).
What does this particular function do and why it's necessary. Why is it declared as **static inline**

```
static inline size_t word_align(size_t size) {
return (size + (sizeof(size_t) - 1)) & ~(sizeof(size_t) - 1);
}
```

I don't understand as well why is there a need for malloc base. Could someone please explain what's happening here. Or even better give me easier example of custom allocator with split/merge.

Comment: This functions "rounds up" the size passed as parameter to the next value that is a multiple of `sizeof(size_t)`.

Comment: You have asked too many questions without being clear. Please ask only one question per posted question. First, you ask what the `word_align` function does. Second, you ask why it is declared `static inline`. Third, you (indirectly) ask why there is a need for “malloc base.” Fourth, it is not clear what “malloc base” is. The code you link to does not contain the word “base”. Fifth, you ask for an explanation of what is happening “here,” which may be asking what is happening in the code you link to. Sixth, you ask for a better allocator example. That is way too much for one post.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I found only one question and some comment to get the scope. Yea, 'why it's necessary' is a second question, but related.

Comment: @harper: The words “what” and “why” appear five times in the question. It is clear multiple different questions are asked, and also clear the post is unclear in several regards.

Answer (score 0):

As Harper mentions the purpose of the function is to find the next memory address that is aligned the same as a **size_t**, but with enough additional space, to store **size** bytes.  Alignment is a big performance concern.  Google **Alignment Performance**. Malloc provides certain guarantees about that.   Static in this case generally means that the function should not be seen outside of the module that it is in.  Google **Internal Linkage**.  Inline is a suggestion to the compiler, that it is free to replace the actual function call by the body of the function to improve performance.  Google **Inline Expansion**.